# Create a Composite Column in Cassandra using Hector Template

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

Requirements:
Composite Column(Not DynamicComposite), Hector Template Implementation

Hi..
I am currently trying to create a columnfamily with the below specs:

```
somekeyId UUID
Site URL UTF8Type
Page URL UTF8Type
   - parentURL UTF8Type (Composite)
   - anchortext UTF8Type (Composite)
```

I have created the following code:

To Create The ColumnFamily:

```
List<ColumnDefinition> columnList = new    ArrayList<ColumnDefinition>();
...

ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDef = HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition(keyspaceName, "page_internal_links", ComparatorType.COMPOSITETYPE, columnList);
    cfDef.setComparatorTypeAlias("(UTF8Type, UTF8Type, UTF8Type)");
    cfDef.setKeyValidationClass(ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE.getTypeName());

Composite key = new Composite();
key.addComponent(parentURL, StringSerializer.get());
key.addComponent(anchorText, StringSerializer.get());

ColumnFamilyTemplate<String, Composite> compTemplate = 
            new ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate<String, Composite>(
                    ksp, "linksCF", StringSerializer.get(), CompositeSerializer.get());
ColumnFamilyUpdater<String, Composite> compUpdater = compTemplate.createUpdater("key"); // In this row key, I want to provide somekeyId UUID
// Any suggestions here ??
compTemplate.update(compUpdater);
```

Thanks for the help in advance. I've been looking for tuts/docs everywhere.. But i ended up nowhere...

Comment: Have you seen: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1 ? It goes into composite column details as well as linking to tutorials built with hector.

Comment: Yes.. But that doesnt talk about Creating Static Composite CF using templats in Hector. It links to composite using old hector methods. Here is the doc for DynamicComposites: https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/DynamicCompositeType-with-templates  . I tried similar approach for static as well(as shown above).. But ends up with some exception.. Is there something for static composites?